# How do you import a "subdependency" in ES6?

Tags: javascript, npm, ecmascript-6, yarnpkg

I have a package `react-router`, which depends on `path-to-regexp`. `react-router` does not export its own import of `path-to-regexp`. In my top-level module, how do I import the exact same `path-to-regexp` that `react-router` uses? Or is this not possible?

For reference, I'm using Yarn as my dependency manager, and I'm considering using its `resolution` configuration for this purpose, but I think version mismatches could become an issue down the line.

If I could `import path from 'react-router/node_modules/path-to-regexp'`, I would, but that doesn't seem to work. If I list `path-to-regexp` as a dependency of my top level module, I could still get version mismatches down the line. Maybe there's a way to use `node-semver` globs to reference the same version as `react-router` in `package.json`?

Comment: Why do you actually want the same version? What if they update to a new version and your own code breaks because of it?

Comment: @loganfsmyth yes, wrote a little bit more about it in the comments of the answer below

Answer (score 0):

I believe using the `resolutions` feature of yarn is the best option. I can't reuse exactly the same module, but I can have a duplicate of exactly the same version in my module. And if there is a version mismatch, `yarn` will let me know with a warning, as described in this [RFC](https://github.com/victornoel/rfcs/blob/bc3e5180211268a92c675c9c7460a714438d999d/accepted/0000-selective-versions-resolutions.md#non-exact-version-specifications). In other words, my `package.json` looks like this...

```
"dependencies": {
  "react-router": "^4.2.0",
  "path-to-regexp": "^1.7.0" <-- same version used by react-router@4.2.0
},
"resolutions": {
  "path-to-regexp": "^1.7.0"
}
```

Comment: What is the perceived issue with react-router using one version **internally** while you use a different version for your purposes?

Comment: @RandyCasburn Just would like to ensure parity of functionality in the event a bug is discovered in path-to-regexp, but doesn't make it into a PR in react-router in time. Probably unnecessary to be this specific, but still an interesting question IMHO